# perform a task when any application installed on device is opened?

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I wish to filter the applications installed on the device so that the person, using that device can't open any app rather than few basic apps... or i wish when he/she opens any application password will be asked......

Comment: What have you tried so far? [did you google](https://www.google.co.in/search?cx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=app+locker+google+code+android&safe=on)?

Comment: Yes i'm trying with the source code provided by the app lock [HERE](http://code.google.com/p/applocker/source/checkout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By reading 'Logcat' logs in the background we can detect other applications launch; as working of any lock application.

Answer (score 2):

That somewhat of a more low level task. I guess you will have to either root the device, or build your own System image and install that on your device.

Comment: No.. actually my basic need is like to make a broadcast receiver which will check each Intent of Launcher category and by which i can filler other applications installed on device....So far i'm messing up with code provided by this [link](http://code.google.com/p/applocker/source/checkout)

Comment: @AnujSharma: "actually my basic need is like to make a broadcast receiver which will check each Intent of Launcher category and by which i can filler other applications installed on device" -- fortunately, there is no such broadcast.

Comment: @CommonsWare ..thanks for your good comment.. i was expecting for a solution if was wrong about broadcast receivers rather than fortunate or unfortunate about android.. thanks again..

Comment: @AnujSharma: You can receive the broadcast, but you can't control in which order the broadcast is received hence there is no 'access control' mechanism you could build from that.

Comment: @Bondax ..thanks mate but if i ask you in simple that how we can show a toast when any application(Applications present on deive e.g. Settings, Contacts, Messages.. etc) is opened?

Comment: @AnujSharma: Why do you need a toast, if you see the app on screen? If your app is hidden, thats more complex, and calls for a seperate question on SO.

Comment: @Bondax... Toast is not my need bro i'm talking about performing an action when user opens any app... toast was just an example..